# how to upgrade A3m 1.01 to current version in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter-a3m

i need email verification of the user in a3m library which is not availble in v1.01 i found in github it is available in v2.0. can anybody please tell me how to upgrade this version to newer or is there any link where i can directly download A3m V2.0

thanks

Answer (score 0):

it has the only version 1 ,
add email verification manually.
get help from authentication library like ion_auth etc.